# jquery reference to several links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need two versions of JQUERY to do two things. The first one is to build a dialogue box that has three buttons, the links are

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the script is

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=UpdateSR.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $('div#thedialog').dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  width: 600,
                  height: 250,
                  buttons: {
                      "No": function () { $('div#thedialog').dialog('close'); alert('Change has not been updated!') },
                      "No, save new draft": function () { $('div#thedialog').dialog('close'); $("[id*=ButtonINSR]").click(); },
                      "Make Final": function () { $('div#thedialog').dialog('close'); $("[id*=ButtonMFSR]").click(); },
                      "Yes": function () { $('div#thedialog').dialog('close'); $("[id*=ButtonUPSR]").click(); alert('Change has been updated!') }
                  }
              });
              $('div#thedialog').dialog('open');
          });
    })
    </script>
```

the second version is to build tooltipster feature, the links are

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../_js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
```

and the script is

```
    $(function () {
        $('#BTEP').tooltipster({    
            content: $('#BTE').show()
        })
    })
    $(function () {
        $('#TOSP').tooltipster({               
            content: $('#TOS').show()
        })
    }) </script>
```

When I put them together, only the tooltopster work well, but not the dialogue. I assume there is a jquery conflict, but I don't know how to solve it? I searched https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
but not sure if it can help. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: "I need two versions of JQUERY to do two things." WRONG. Disaster waiting to happen. Get this idea out of your head now, please!

Comment: jquery 1.7.0 also has an associated version of jQuery UI with a dialog widget.

Comment: try remove 1.4.2 jQuery and move the 1.7.0 jQuery to the top of the referenced files

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. As I'm new to JQuery, I don't think I can figure out the codes in those links in the short term. But I'm glad that $.noConflict(); works well, I added var $jq2 = $.noConflict(); in my second scripts, and use $jq2 to replace $. It works well.